# Is there such thing as a MIME type for all audio and video like "audio/*" and "video/*"?

Tags: c++, audio, video, qt5, mime-types

I'm writing an application in which, in a drag and drop, I want to accept only audio and video types.

This is the code in Qt5 for a drop in a widget:

```
void DragDropFrame::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* evt)
{
    if (frame_type == FRAME_TYPE::DROPPABLE)
    {
        if (evt->mimeData()->hasFormat("audio/*"))
        {
            evt->acceptProposedAction();
        }
        else
            evt->ignore();
    }
    else
        evt->ignore();
}
```

Yet "audio/*" does not work. The widget does not accept any file. Do I have to "if-else" all possibile audio and video MIME-types or is there another quicker solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no general-purpose MIME type like that.

The `evt` will tell you the specific MIME type(s) it holds.  You can do substring/pattern matching to see if any types match what you are looking for, eg:

```
void DragDropFrame::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* evt)
{
    if (frame_type == FRAME_TYPE::DROPPABLE)
    {
        QStringList formats = evt->mimeData()->formats();
        if (!formats.filter("audio/").empty() ||
            !formats.filter("video/").empty())
        {
            evt->acceptProposedAction();
            return;
        }
    }

    evt->ignore();
}
```

Alternatively:

```
void DragDropFrame::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* evt)
{
    if (frame_type == FRAME_TYPE::DROPPABLE)
    {
        QRegExp regex("\\b(audio|video)/*", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
        if (!evt->mimeData()->formats().filter(regex).empty())
        {
            evt->acceptProposedAction();
            return;
        }
    }

    evt->ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`QMimeData::hasFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#hasFormat) does not process any kind of wildcards. It simply checks whether the mimetype you specify exists as-is in the list of supported formats (see [the implementation](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/kernel/qmimedata.cpp#L560)).

You will need to get the list of supported [`formats()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#formats) and search it for any string starting with `audio/` or `video/`.